# dhtmlx grid smartrender not work normally after sorting with splitAt mode

Tags: grid, dhtmlx

I use **split mode** and **smartrender** in dhtmlx grid. After I sort rows, rendered rows disappear and never come out on the right side, like the following picture.

[after sorting, rows on right side could not be rendered anymore(click here to view the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZtjz.jpg)

It's strange, rows on the left could be rendered when I scrolling on both sides.But rows on right side could not be rendered.

Anyone helps?
Thanks!

code structure:

```
var grid = new dhtmlXGridObject('#container');
grid.setImagePath("./bower_components/dhtmlxSuitePro/4.1.1/codebase/imgs/");
grid.enableTreeCellEdit(false);
grid.setHeader('...');
grid.attachHeader('...');
grid.setInitWidths('...');
grid.setColAlign('...');
grid.setColTypes('...');
grid.setColSorting('...');

grid.splitAt(2);
grid.enableSmartRendering(true);

grid.init();
grid.parse(data,'json'); // data is defined
```

Comment: Is there any style on the page that is interfering with your grid? There may be something in the xml or a JS error! As such in split mode grid scroll fine on both side. Can you share your code?

Comment: There are no errors in console. I have given my code structure in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after reading the docs again, I found `grid.enableSmartRendering(true);` should be after `grid.init();`

code following works:

```
var grid = new dhtmlXGridObject('#container');
grid.setImagePath("./bower_components/dhtmlxSuitePro/4.1.1/codebase/imgs/");
grid.enableTreeCellEdit(false);
grid.setHeader('...');
grid.attachHeader('...');
grid.setInitWidths('...');
grid.setColAlign('...');
grid.setColTypes('...');
grid.setColSorting('...');
grid.init();

grid.splitAt(2);
grid.enableSmartRendering(true);

grid.parse(data,'json'); // data is defined
```

Comment: Actually the more important thing is that the splitAt() method ahould be called after the init only