# dhtmlxgrid smart rendering and split mode error after sorting

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

When I use dhtmlxgrid with smartrendering and split mode, I found a error after sorting. I have posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157170/dhtmlx-grid-smartrender-not-work-normally-after-sorting-with-splitat-mode/39157517).

I thought I had solved the problem, but I didn't.

After some testing, I found that when I use smart rendering and split mode, error appears after sorting rows.

```
var mygrid;
myGrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
myGrid.setImagePath("../../../codebase/imgs/");
myGrid.setHeader("Sales,Book Title,Author,Price,In Store,Shipping,Bestseller,Date of Publication");
myGrid.setInitWidths("50,80,250,70,70,70,70,100");
myGrid.setColAlign("right,left,left,right,center,left,center,center");
myGrid.setColTypes("ed,ed,ed,price,ch,co,ro,ro");
var combobox = myGrid.getCombo(5);
combobox.put("1","1 Hour");
combobox.put("12","12 Hours");
combobox.put("24","24 Hours");
combobox.put("48","2 days");
combobox.put("168","1 week");
combobox.put("pick","pick up");
combobox.put("na","na");
myGrid.setColSorting("na,na,na,na,na,na,na,na");
myGrid.attachEvent("onXLS",function(){ document.getElementById("a_1").style.display="block"; });
myGrid.attachEvent("onXLE",function(){ document.getElementById("a_1").style.display="none"; });
myGrid.enableAutoWidth(true)
myGrid.init();
myGrid.enableSmartRendering(true);
myGrid.splitAt(2);
myGrid.load("../common/smartrend.xml");
```

In previous given code demo, sorting is disabled by `myGrid.setColSorting("na,na,na,na,na,na,na,na");`. Does it mean this function hasn't been finished yet?

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: In case of using the static smart rendering (no dynamic loading of data) the split+srnd combination should work correctly.
For the dynamic loading of data the client sorting won't work.
Please, share with the text of occurring error or with a demo link, where the problem can be reconstructed locally.